# Radio button group inside another radio button group in Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I am programming my first application in Android Studio. The user should select the training type (muscle gain, weight loss, own program) and then choose sex (male/female). So, 6 possible outcomes and 2 respective radio groups. After choosing necessary options user hits confirm button and goes to necessary screen with training type (using one of 6 addListeneronbutton methods). But app does not react after installation.
Would you please tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Muscles:
                switch (view.getId()){
                    case R.id.Male:
                        addListenerOnButton();
                    case R.id.Female:
                        addListenerOnButton2();
                }
                break;
        case R.id.Diet:
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.Male:
                    addListenerOnButton3();
                case R.id.Female:
                    addListenerOnButton4();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Own:
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.Male:
                    addListenerOnButton3();
                case R.id.Female:
                    addListenerOnButton4();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Respective xml file has following code for choosing sex:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Male"
        android:text="Male"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/Female"
        android:text="Female"
        android:onclick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Inside the same xml second radio group for choosing training type:

```
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/Muscles"
            android:text="@string/Muscles"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Diet"
            android:text="@string/Fat"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Own"
            android:text="@string/Own"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Why nested groups? Can't your app just figure it out based on the values of two separate radio groups?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is far more complicated than necessary. What you need is two separate radio groups. Instead of executing code when each radio button is clicked, you should have the event on the button.

When the user clicks on the button, it should check that both fields have been checked and then pass *those two values* on the next screen. Then you would deal with interpreting user input.

So, the solution is simplicity.

Comment: Ramsay, here what I though would make an improvement, but it does not.  Would you please type how tipically would code look like when you "check that both fields were selected and then pas values on the next screen"

Comment: I've separated onClick in two:

Answer (score 0):

```
public int onRadioButtonClicked (View view){
    return view.getId();
}

public int onRadioButtonClicked2 (View view2){
    return view2.getId();
}
```

And then, I do not know how to get simpler way than nested statements like this:

```
Button button;


public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            switch(onRadioButtonClicked2(arg0)) {
                case R.id.Muscles:
                    switch (onRadioButtonClicked(arg0)) {
                        case R.id.Male:
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MaleMuscules.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.Female:
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, FemaleMuscules.class);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.Diet:
                    switch (onRadioButtonClicked(arg0)) {
                        case R.id.Male:
                            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, MaleLoss.class);
                            startActivity(intent3);
                            break;
                        case R.id.Female:
                            Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, FemaleLoss.class);
                            startActivity(intent4);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.Own:
                    switch (onRadioButtonClicked(arg0))
                    {
                        case R.id.Male:
                            Intent intent5 = new Intent(context, MaleOwn.class);
                            startActivity(intent5);
                            break;
                        case R.id.Female:
                            Intent intent6 = new Intent(context, FemaleOwn.class);
                            startActivity(intent6);
                            break;
                    }
                  break;
            }
        }

    });

}
```